# How to make the title changer compatible with many?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Well, I have a title changer so if the division or the element is visible to the viewport, the title will change according to the title attribute in a division. The problem is that it is only compatible with a ONE division only. It doesn't work or it isn't compatible with many division.

[For Live Testing/Viewing](http://stackoverflow.prospekt.ml/bugs/scrollTitleJS/) 

[jsFiddle - For Viewing of Codes](https://jsfiddle.net/astroXoom/q45mc8dr/)

My Javascript Code:

```
// Viewport Configuration - Please don't edit this!
$.fn.is_on_screen = function(){
    var win = $(window);
    var viewport = {
        top : win.scrollTop(),
        left : win.scrollLeft()
    };
    viewport.right = viewport.left + win.width();
    viewport.bottom = viewport.top + win.height();

    var bounds = this.offset();
    bounds.right = bounds.left + this.outerWidth();
    bounds.bottom = bounds.top + this.outerHeight();

    return (!(viewport.right < bounds.left || viewport.left > bounds.right || viewport.bottom < bounds.top || viewport.top > bounds.bottom));
};
// End Viewport Configuraton

// This is the main config of the checkpage.js -- Feel free to edit it into your own config
if( $('.target').length > 0 ) { // If the target element exists
    if( $('.target').is_on_screen() ) { // Show this if the target element is existing after loading the DOM
      document.title = $('.target')[0].title; // This shows the target title attribute if it visible
    } else {
        document.title = "Prospekt | A Gaming Community"; // Show this if the element isn't in the Viewport
    }
}
$(window).scroll(function(){ // Bind Windows Scroll Event
    if( $('.target').length > 0 ) { // Show this if the element exists in DOM
        if( $('.target').is_on_screen() ) { // Show this if the element is visible to DOM
            document.title = $('.target')[0].title; // This shows the target title attribute if it visible
        } else {
        document.title = "Prospekt | A Gaming Community"; // If the article isn't there, change the title to default
        }
    }
});
// End Main Config
```

My HTML Body Code:

```
    <div id="a1">
      <p> The title is normal, but when you hover down... </p>
    </div>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>

    <div id="a2" class="target label label-info 1" title="Article 2 | Prospekt">
      <p style="padding:5px"> Stackoverflow is an amazing place! Please check your title if someting happened! *something happens magically* </p>
    </div>

    <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>

        <div id="a1" class="target label label-info" title="Article 3 | Prospekt">
          <p style="padding:5px"> This is the 3rd article, the title should change lol </p>
        </div>

        <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>

            <div id="a2" class="target label label-info" title="Article 4 | Prospekt">
              <p style="padding:5px"> This is the 4th Article, Something on the title should happen or it should change </p>
            </div>

            <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>

                <div id="a1" class="target label label-info" title="Article 5 | Prospekt">
                  <p style="padding:5px"> Prospekt | A Gaming Community <br> &copy Kirk Niverba and Stackoverflow for helping me to finish the scrollTitleJS! </p>
                </div>
<br>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "division"? Also, you might want to think about reducing the amount of break lines.

Comment: division or <div> tag, I use the break lines just for the viewing purpose, i will remove it when the site became live.

Comment: <div> :<div id="a2" class="target label label-info 1" title="Article 2 | Prospekt">

Comment: You might want to look into something like this: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#scrollspy for your needs

Comment: Sorry but i've got it on my own codes, can you still help me tho?

Comment: How about asking the guy who wrote the jQuery snippet: http://upshots.org/javascript/jquery-test-if-element-is-in-viewport-visible-on-screen

Answer (score 0):

To start off with, your current implementation makes it impossible to have dynamically changing titles, as you always set the title to `$('.target')[0].title`, which will always take the title from the first node of the object list (yes, `$('.target')` returns more than element in this case). Additionally, you are only checking whether the very first `div` is on screen and ignoring all others.

What you need to do is loop through all found elements and check each one, whether it's on screen, stopping at the first on screen one or, if not a single one is on screen, returning the default title.

Example:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){ // Bind Windows Scroll Event
    if( $('.target').length > 0 ) { // Run this if we have at least one target element
        $('.target').each(function() { //Check eac
            if( $(this).is_on_screen() ) { // Check if the element is visible to the user
                document.title = $(this)[0].title; // Show the target title attribute
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Note this example is missing checks I mentioned above and is only to be taken as a rough idea of how it could be done.